# Search in files excluding #if debug sections

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, search

Is there a way to find in files (or solution) but ignoring results that are between #if debug / #endif sections?

Or is there a nice plugin that does such a thing, or a neat workaround?

Comment: Have yo tried exclusive regex?

Comment: Yes but I have not got that to work in Notepad++ or Visual Studio

Comment: Here's some: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122986/is-it-ok-to-leave-what-have-you-tried-comments

Comment: Oh no not the m*** word! :-) anyway I didn't keep what I tried so I can't post them. But it is what you might expect - treat the whole file as a single string then use lookaheads or lookbehinds. But regex isn't a CSG so it will always fall short. Anyway what I did in the end was write some C# to create a clone directory structure and files of my project but with the .cs files having the #debug parts stripped out. Indexed that using Windows index and now I can search that folder instead.